# My Makefile is trying to compile a non-exsistent/made up filename

Tags: makefile

This is my VERY FIRST Makefile and so I have cut and paste junk I have found all over the web. My directory structure is pretty flat and was not thought out for Makefiles. It is:
Project/
Project/Control
Project/NodeMgmt
Project/Common
Project/Interfaces

I am writing a Makefile for Control and would like it to standalone inside Control. It needs to include compile and include from Common & Interfaces. Here's my Makefile:

```
CC = g++

CFLAGS = -Wall -c

INCLUDES = -I/usr/local/include -I/SuperCool/Ion-1.0.0-snapshot-1/include -I/SuperCool/FastrakSDK-4.0.1-snapshot-1/include/Fastrak/Engine/Core/CoreIpc -I/Projects/Common -I/Projects/Interfaces -I/Projects/NodeMgmt -I/Projects/Controller 

LFLAGS = -L/usr/local/lib -L/SuperCool/FastrakSDK-4.0.1-snapshot-1/lib

LIBS = -lCoreIpc4 -lIonOs

VPATH = ../Interfaces/
VPATH = ../Common/
VPATH = ../NodeMgmt/

SRCS = *.cc

OBJS = $(SRCS:.cc=.o)

MAIN = controller

.PHONY: clean

all:    $(MAIN)
    @echo Built Controller

$(MAIN): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(MAIN) $(OBJS) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.cc.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) *.o $(MAIN)
```

It's compiling the first .cc file it finds "-c Controller.cc -o *.o" which make sense but that's all it's compiling and I get a *.o output file, not a Controller.o file. It does not compile any other files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one problem:

```
SRCS = *.cc
```

Make doesn't understand wildcards without the `wildcard` function:

```
SRCS = $(wildcard *.cc)
```

That should get it working; we can make minor improvements later.

Comment: Thanks that was great, they all compile. Now the files in Common/ and Interfaces/ don't get compiled so when I try and link, it barfs. I thought that all sources would be taken from VPATH?

Comment: I just updated my SRCS to SRCS = $(wildcard ../Common/*.cc ../Interfaces/*.cc *.cc), a hack I know but still won't link. Do I need another method or how do I update my OBJS variable the same way?

Comment: @jnbbender, you have to make some design decisions. Suppose you have `Common/foo.cc` and `Interfaces/bar.cc`; should `foo.o` go into `Common/` and `bar.o` into `Interfaces/`? Or should both go into `Control/`?

Comment: They are logically separate. Interfaces are pre-processed files, i.e. protocol buffers files, and Common files are shared among another 2 separate Client/ and Server/ directories. Utlimately I would like the Client and Server to be built independently using the defined protocol buffers interface with a few Common shared C++ classes between the 2. That's the goal.